# How can I create a percent encoded URL from complete URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

The input url is mixed ascii and multi byte code.
And I can't change this strings.
I would like to download this url, but an error occured `ordinal not in range(128)`.

```
input_url = "http://sample.jp/api?v1=aaa&v2=日本語&v3=ccc"

req = urllib.request.Request(input_url)
resp = None
try:
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
    print(e.reason)  # I had an error `ordinal not in range(128)`
return resp
```

First, I tried `urllib.parse.quote()` but the result is `http%3a%2f%2fsample%2ejp%2fapi%3fv1%3daaa%26v2%3d%93%fa%96%7b%8c%ea%26v3%3dccc`. I had another error `ValueError: unknown url type`.
How can I resolve this problem? Or do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of urllib, and urlparse should do it for you:

```
>>> urllib.urlencode(urlparse.parse_qsl(urlparse.urlparse(input_url).query))
'v1=aaa&v2=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E&v3=ccc'
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine on Python3.
`from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qsl, urlencode
urlencode(parse_qsl(urlparse(input_url).query))`
Genious! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode those parameters to UTF-8 bytes and the bytes toURL percent encoding. You can do all this with the [`urllib.parse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlencode

parsed = urlparse(input_url)
query = parse_qs(parsed.query)
fixed_url = parsed._replace(query=urlencode(query, doseq=True)).geturl()
```

Demo:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlencode
>>> input_url = "http://sample.jp/api?v1=aaa&v2=日本語&v3=ccc"
>>> parsed = urlparse(input_url)
>>> query = parse_qs(parsed.query)
>>> parsed._replace(query=urlencode(query, doseq=True)).geturl()
'http://sample.jp/api?v1=aaa&v2=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E&v3=ccc'
>>> import urllib.request
>>> urllib.request.urlopen(_)
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x108f0f7b8>
```

Comment: `>>> urllib.unquote('v1=%5B%27aaa%27%5D')
"v1=['aaa']"`

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice and Demo.
I tried but I got `http://sample.jp/api?v2=['日本語']&v3=['ccc']&v1=['aaa']`.
However I understood that I had to encode to UTF-8 and I could use urlparse, parse_qs, urlencode. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MaikoOhkawa: mea culpa, the doseq flag needed to be set.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I misunderstood. I forgot to set the doseq flag. It works completely fine when I add `doseq=True`. I see. When doseq is True, I can get sequential strings. I learned. Thank you very much for your advice!