# How can I distinguish percent encoded URL and NOT percent encoded URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I receive 2 pattern URL, percent encoded and NOT percent encoded.
Then my code don't work with `input_url_B` because it already encoded.
How can I resolve it or do you have some ideas?

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlencode

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_url_A = "http://sample.jp/api?v1=aaa&v2=日本語&v3=ccc"
    input_url_B = "http://sample.jp/api?v1=aaa&v2=%93%fa%96%7b%8c%eav3=ccc"  # '%93%fa%96%7b%8c%ea' = '日本語'

    # Pattern A is OK.
    parsed = urlparse(input_url_A)
    query = parse_qs(parsed.query)
    fixed_url = parsed._replace(query=urlencode(query, doseq=True)).geturl()
    print(fixed_url)  # 'http://sample.jp/api?v3=ccc&v2=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E&v1=aaa'
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(fixed_url)

    # Pattern B is NG.
    parsed = urlparse(input_url_B)
    query = parse_qs(parsed.query)
    fixed_url = parsed._replace(query=urlencode(query, doseq=True)).geturl()
    print(fixed_url) # 'http://sample.jp/api?v2=%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%7B%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDv3%3Dccc&v1=aaa'
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(fixed_url)
```

ref:
My previous question.
[How can I create a percent encoded URL from complete URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010484/how-can-i-create-a-percent-encoded-url-from-complete-url)

Comment: Could you simply check if the URL already contains `%` and then decide whether or not to encode?

Comment: Thank you for your advice and sorry for the late response. I'm having trouble yet. Then I'm tring your idea. Thank you.